# How to move multiple lines to join another using notepad++

Tags: merge, notepad++

I have file with many lines look as:

```
1431683268.M60282P30030.mailtest,S=23479,W=23938:0453D37C43E8=
923D
1431683268.M690986P30032.mailtest,S=23459,W=23918:04543801693F=
9F0A
1431683272.M58906P30033.mailtest,S=23469,W=23928:044506F90B17=
A602
```

How can i merge lines using notepad++ so they look:

```
1431683268.M60282P30030.mailtest,S=23479,W=23938:0453D37C43E8923D
1431683268.M690986P30032.mailtest,S=23459,W=23918:04543801693F9F0A
1431683272.M58906P30033.mailtest,S=23469,W=23928:044506F90B17A602
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Find what: `=\R`
Replace with: `NOTHING`

Then click on <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: @Serg: Have you checked `Regular expression`?

Comment: yes i check "Regular Expression" on Find and Replace form

Comment: @Serg: Strange, it works fine for me. Do you really have an equal sign at the end of the line? You could try with `[\r\n]+` instead of `\R`

Comment: Ow Sorry! Now i updated version Notepad++ and your method works fine! Thanks!